# Get value from Managed Metadata Field in Drop Down List

Tags: managed-metadata, dropdown

I'm working on a project portal where a user can create a project (team site). The user is asked to fill in details regarding the projects. One of the things that is required is a Managed Metadata field.

When the user so creates this projects, we have a dropdown list on the left side, listing all the data in this MMD category. As default, the dropdown list is set to pick the top one (alphabetically). I want the default value in this field to be the value the user chose when he created the project.

If the user selects multiple values, i want the drop-down list to show either the first value the user picked.

Any tips on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43249/managed-metadata-and-the-client-om) is related to this one. See answer there how to retrieve the identifiers from Managed Metadata fields. I hope this helps.