# Managed Metadata and the client OM

Tags: client-object-model

Is it possible to return  the values of a Managed Metadata field assigned to a document using strictly the client object model?  Note that I want to return ALL the possible values and allow the user to choose one, perhaps via a treeview or comboboxes, just to let the user assign a predefined value to the field.  The user does not need to change the values in the field.  I only wantt to display the possible values, allow one to be chosen and assign the chosen value to the field.  Thank You,
-Derek

Answer (score 7):

I had the same question and searched the internet some code examples. I found some code fragments but no easy & complete working solution. So I created this code to do the two steps:

1. Get the **SspId** and **TermSetId** from a Managed Metadata column
   in a custom content-type.
2. Use this information to execute the
       **GetTermSets** method on the Taxonomy Webservice and parse the result into a usable list or tree.
3. Use the value from the  MetadataItem when setting the value for a
   **ListItem**

Details:
**Step 1.**

```
var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://localhost/sites/STS20120731101501");
var properties = clientContext.GetTaxonomyFieldProperties("MyCustomContentType", "MyManagedMetadataColumn");
string sspId = properties["SspId"]; // e40374fb-a6cc-4854-989f-c1d94a7967ee
string termSetId = properties["TermSetId"]; // 9eeec005-4818-486f-b4d8-bda1d43d42b4
```

**Step 2.**

```
using (var client = new TaxonomywebserviceSoapClient())
{
    string sspID = "e40374fb-a6cc-4854-989f-c1d94a7967ee";
    string termsetId = "9eeec005-4818-486f-b4d8-bda1d43d42b4";
    var items = client.GetMetadataItems(sspID, termsetId);

    foreach (var item in items.AsTree())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', item.Level) + item);
    }

    var firstMetadataItem = items.First(); // Just take the first as an example.
}
```

**Step 3.**

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://localhost/sites/STS20120731101501"))
{
  var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList");

  var newListItem = list.AddItem(new ListItemCreationInformation());
  newListItem["SomeNormalField"] = "SomeText";
  newListItem["MyManagedMetadataColumn"] = firstMetadataItem.ToString(); // This will be like "MyFirstValue|643b827f-5fed-4a34-8270-ed0c662df639"

  newListItem.Update();
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

The extension methods : **GetTaxonomyFieldProperties**, **GetMetadataItems** and **AsTree** can be found [here](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=ff58a5e0db16681c&id=FF58A5E0DB16681C!529).

*References*

- http://youcode.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/managed-metadata-using-taxonomy-web-service/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/11/18/how-to-work-with-managed-metadata-columns-by-using-the-sharepoint-client-object-model-kaushalendra-kumar.aspx
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/9709b87c-a5af-4b8f-82c1-c18f18f1e967

Comment: thanks, i've got the tree sorted out but i can't for the life of me figure out how to then set the value of the field.  i've got lots of samples but they are all converted from c# maybe something was lost along the way?

Comment: Setting the data is very easy, just use item["MyManagedMetadataColumn"] = item.ToString();

Comment: thanks again but now i get value does not fall within expected range

Comment: If fldtypes(i) = "TaxonomyFieldType" Then
                    list1(fldnames(i)) = tv.SelectedNode.Text.ToString
                End If <br>listl.update <br> br represents line breaks since everytime i hit enter it just posts context.executequery

Comment: This helped me a lot, even though some tweaks was needed to make it work in SharePoint 2013. For example the TaxonomywebserviceSoapClient seem to have changed name to Taxonomywebservice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Please have a look at the following link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/11/18/how-to-work-with-managed-metadata-columns-by-using-the-sharepoint-client-object-model-kaushalendra-kumar.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot but i don't want to use TaxonomyHiddenList, as that is only populated with values that have been assigned to a document in the past. I want ALL possible terms. However I am new to Sharepoint so it's possible I just misunderstood something in the article you posted. Please let me know.